# Concatenate csv-files with the same name from subdirectories

Tags: linux, csv, bash-scripting, concatenation

I found some scripts concatenating text files from different subdirectories, but all of them produced output files like "output.txt", but didn't keep the original file name.

Structure

```
Folder_A
   a.csv
   b.csv
   ...

Folder_B
   a.csv
   b.csv
   ...
```

I would like to receive a new a.csv, merged from the a.csv in Folder_A and the a.csv in Folder_B and so on, written either to the parent directory or a new output-directory.

In my case, the number of files in the subdirectories are similar.
There could be more than two subdirectories.

The resulting csv-files should only contain one header line.

I know that I have to loop through the directories, but I have no idea how to create a list of file names and search for them, and how to nest all this.

Any help kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this bash script. It finds files named '.csv' in the first directory and concatenates it with the same filename found 
in the 2nd directory, after deleting (1d) its 1st line (csv header).
The resulting file is in the 3rd directory.

```
a=Folder_A
b=Folder_B
c=Folder_C
mkdir -p $c
(cd $a && find . -type f -name '*.csv') |
while read file
do    ( cat "$a/$file"
        [ -f "$b/$file" ] && sed '1d' <"$b/$file"
      ) >"$c/$file"
done
```

---

This bash script finds files named '.csv' in the directories given
as argument and concatenates them with any of the same filename found 
later, after deleting (1d) their 1st line (csv header).
The resulting file is in the Folder_concat directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
dest=Folder_concat
mkdir -p $dest
find "$@" -name "$dest" -prune -o -name '*.csv' |
while read file
do    base=$(basename "$file")
      if [ -s "$dest/$base" ]
      then sed '1d' <"$file"
      else cat "$file"
      fi >>"$dest/$base"
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This one worked for me. Btw, is there way to avoid hardcoding the folder names ? There might be also 10 or 50 or 100 subfolders ... (luckily not now)

Comment: @BerndV.  Do you want to find all the files called a.csv wherever they are and merge them into one file of the same name, and similarly for all filenames *.csv?

Comment: Yes I would like to find all a.csv in the subfolders of the current directory and have them concatenated to a new a.csv in the current directory (or in an "output"-folder") and so on for any other csv. These csvs are exported tables from Access mdbs with the exact same table layout, which I need to merge for further processing. (Do not need new mdb, I'm pretty happy with csv as I read them into R)

Comment: Ahh, just saw your updated answer. fi >>"$dest/base" was missing a $ at base, but now it runs smoothly and everything looks perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Easier if you do it more Unix-y, more shelly -- only 2 commands required:

1. get list of the filenames (=Distinct Union of all dirs' files)
2. cat all dirs' part-file(s) into Output dir's whole-file(s)

`#### get list of files as Distinct Union of all dirs' files
 #   (alas, basename can only handle ONE filename at a time
 #    so have to loop through them)`

```
DISTINCTUNION_ALLFILES=`
  for FILE in Folder_{A,B,C,D}/*
  do
    basename $FILE
  done  | sort  | uniq

  `
# 
# syntax explanation:
#  1. for VARIABLE in LIST: loops b/w DO and DONE, with Variable taking each value in the list
#  2. {A,B,C} is Shell (bash) expansion: creates N words, 1 for each comma-separated sub-word
#           e.g.: dir{A,B}            -> dirA  dirB     
#           e.g.: myfile.{dll,o,out}  -> myfile.dll  myfile.o  myfile.out
#           e.g.: myfile{,.tmp}       -> myfile  myfile.tmp
#  3. BASENAME strips away the Path leaving just the filename (cf.Dirname for the opposite)
#  4. the BACKQUOTES (``) take the command's Output and re-place it on that part of the commandline
#  5. | takes the total output and Sorts it, then | takes _that_ to Uniq which removes duplicates
#  6. the whole lot is then stored in the VariableName



#### cat all dirs' part-file(s) into Output dir's whole-file(s)

for FILE in $DISTINCTUNION_ALLFILES
do
    cat Folder_{A,B,C,D}/$FILE  > OutputDir/$FILE
done
#
# syntax explanation:
# 1. same For loop as before, same filename expansion as before
# 2. files which are not in ALL dirs will generate errors but won't stop the conCATenation
# 3. result goes into OutputDir, 1 file per filename
```

Comment: Sorry, I mislead you with the folder names. The Folder_A, Folder_B was just for showing the structure. They have completely other names without any pattern. Trying to change that in the script failed. Same as in the other answer: Is there a way to avoid hard coding the subfolder names?